# Add content to the last slide of each product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How would I add content as a last slide image for each WooCommerce product?

Examples of this are shown on the 2 links below. You will see once you go to the last slide there is an extra slide which contains a form.

https://www.artsper.com/en/contemporary-artworks/painting/717489/balloon-girl-self-destructed-by-dr-love-banksy-tribute

https://www.singulart.com/en/artworks/elena-dmitrenko-fisherman-266339